# How can I prevent Thyemleaf from urlencoding my template?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

We have the following thymeleaf config:

```
    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("templates/*"));
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver() {
        final StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setOrder(2);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }
```

That is - two resolvers, one for html, one for text.

We use the html one for the body of our emails, the text one for the subject.

Given:

- a subject "template" (a plain string) like this: `"[[${values.createdBy}]] created a widget"`
- a `values.createdBy` value of `Brock O'Samson`

We are seeing the result:`Brock O&#39;Samson`

Any ideas what to config? The "template mode" seemed like the obvious solution, but it was already set to TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two independent approaches:

- Use [th:utext](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text) tag attribute
- Set template mode in `stringTemplateResolver()` to [`TemplateMode.LEGACYHTML5`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.0.BETA01/org/thymeleaf/templatemode/TemplateMode.html#LEGACYHTML5) (deprecated)

Comment: Thanks! The utext attribute helped me elsewhere in the email template. It looks like since my specific issue was text inlining, the real solution was to use the unespecaped inline syntax:
```[(${values.createdBy})]``` - note the parens inside the outer square brackets